# Matrix form of Overlap-add

Tags: linear-systems, matrix, linear-algebra, overlap-add

We know overlap-add of a en-framed signal can be done easily by following code

```
function y = overlapAdd(frame, hop)
frameLen = size(frame, 1);
nframes = size(frame, 2);
xlen = frameLen + (nframes-1)*hop;
y = zeros(xlen, 1);
for l = 1 : nframes
    y(1+(l-1)*hop : frameLen+(l-1)*hop) = y(1+(l-1)*hop : frameLen+(l-1)*hop) + frame(:, l);
end
```

My question is, is there a computation form of overlap-add that uses solely matrix multiplication?

Since overlap-add is a linear operation, it can be represented by one or more matrix multiplications.

Comment: hah! For overlap-add to be a linear operation, how do you formulate the input?

Answer (score 0):

Forming a square matrix with mostly zeros but each input frame along rows, shifted by eg half a frame each, then summing (accumulating) each column seems like the most intuitive matrix operation here?

Eg

```
 tmp = …
[x1 x2 0 0 …
 0  y1 y2 0 …
 0  0  z1 z2]
Out = sum(tmp, 1);
```